# How do I make a TOC at the top of a tutorial page in Wolfram Workbench?

Tags: documentation, workbench

At the top of the [Complex Polynomial Systems](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ComplexPolynomialSystems.html) page in the Wolfram Documentation Center, there is a table of contents with each item linking to the appropriate headers below (*Mathematica* 9 and above).

[image]

How do I create this style of table of contents in Wolfram Workbench for my own tutorials?  I am using Workbench 2.0.

A solution that requires Workbench 3.0 is acceptable.

Comment: I'd like to see, too, how to do this directly in the Front End of Mathematica.

Comment: What is that fabled Workbench 3.0 you speak about?

Comment: I'd love to see a solution without workbench!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table of contents is generated automatically by Workbench 3.0, which you need to request from Wolfram because it hasn't been officially released.

Workbench will generate a link for each "Section" cell that you include in your tutorial.

Edit:
If you have Workbench 3 but don't want to use it directly, you can load the `DocumentationBuild` package that comes with it and run the `ConvertNotebook` function on an authoring notebook created using the DocumentationTools palette.

Comment: @M.R. I added a way for you to do this from outside Workbench (but you still need to have the packages that come with Workbench).

Answer (score 4):

These type of TOC cells as shown in 'tutorial/ComplexPolynomialSystems#934984887', here's an explanation that doesn't use the workbench:

```
titles = {"Section A", "Section B", "Section C", "Section D"};

Clear[f]; 
f[s_] := TemplateBox[{Cell[
    s], (SetSelectedNotebook[EvaluationNotebook[]]; 
    NotebookLocate[s] &), upChevron, downChevron}, "MyTOCIcon", 
  BaseStyle -> {"MyTOC"}];
grid = Partition[f /@ titles, UpTo[2]];
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[GridBox[grid]], "TutorialJumpBox"]
cs = Cell[#, "Section", CellTags -> {#}] & /@ titles;
Scan[CellPrint, cs]
```

[image]

For this to work you need to run these styling commands to define "MyTOC" and "MyTOCIcon" (I added a few others) and the chevron icons:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[
      StyleData[
       StyleDefinitions -> 
        FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb"]]], 
     Cell[StyleData["Input"], CellContext -> Notebook], 
     Cell[StyleData["Output"], CellContext -> Notebook], 
     Cell[StyleData["TutorialMoreAboutSection"], 
      CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 30}], 
     Cell[StyleData["RelatedTutorialsSection"], 
      CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 30}], 
     Cell[StyleData["TutorialRelatedLinksSection"], 
      CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 30}],
     Cell[StyleData["MyTOC"], Editable -> False, 
      FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12, 
      FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.360784]], 
     Cell[StyleData["MyTOCIcon"], 
      TemplateBoxOptions -> {DisplayFunction :> (TagBox[
            DynamicBox[
             If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
              ButtonBox[
               RowBox[{#4, Cell["  "], 
                 StyleBox[#, 
                  FontColor -> 
                   RGBColor[0.854902, 0.396078, 0.145098]]}], 
               ButtonFunction -> #2], 
              ButtonBox[RowBox[{#3, Cell["  "], #}], 
               ButtonFunction -> #2]]], 
            MouseAppearanceTag["LinkHand"]] &)}, 
      ButtonBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> {FontColor -> 
           GrayLevel[0.360784], "Link"}}]
     }, Visible -> False, 
    StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]];

upChevron = 
  GraphicsBox[
   TagBox[RasterBox[
     RawArray[
      "UnsignedInteger8", {{{128, 128, 128, 32}, {128, 128, 128, 
         16}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 
         0}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 
         48}}, {{128, 128, 128, 48}, {128, 128, 128, 239}, {128, 128, 
         128, 112}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128,
          128, 16}, {128, 128, 128, 143}, {128, 128, 128, 
         239}}, {{128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 64}, {128, 128, 
         128, 223}, {128, 128, 128, 191}, {128, 128, 128, 112}, {128, 
         128, 128, 223}, {128, 128, 128, 191}, {128, 128, 128, 
         32}}, {{128, 128, 128, 32}, {128, 128, 128, 16}, {128, 128, 
         128, 16}, {128, 128, 128, 175}, {128, 128, 128, 255}, {128, 
         128, 128, 127}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 
         48}}, {{128, 128, 128, 48}, {128, 128, 128, 239}, {128, 128, 
         128, 112}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 16}, {128, 
         128, 128, 16}, {128, 128, 128, 143}, {128, 128, 128, 
         239}}, {{128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 64}, {128, 128, 
         128, 223}, {128, 128, 128, 191}, {128, 128, 128, 112}, {128, 
         128, 128, 223}, {128, 128, 128, 191}, {128, 128, 128, 
         32}}, {{128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 
         128, 16}, {128, 128, 128, 175}, {128, 128, 128, 255}, {128, 
         128, 128, 127}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 
         0}}, {{128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128,
          0}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 16}, {128, 128, 128,
          0}, {128, 128, 128, 0}, {128, 128, 128, 0}}}], {{0, 8}, {8, 
       0}}, {0, 255}, ColorFunction -> RGBColor], 
    BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
     Interleaving -> True, Magnification -> Automatic], 
    Selectable -> False], DefaultBaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics", 
   ImageSizeRaw -> {8, 8}, PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
   ImageSize -> {8, 9}];

downChevron = 
  GraphicsBox[
   TagBox[RasterBox[
     RawArray[
      "UnsignedInteger8", {{{229, 95, 28, 32}, {229, 95, 28, 
         16}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 
         0}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 
         48}}, {{229, 95, 28, 48}, {229, 95, 28, 239}, {229, 95, 28, 
         112}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 
         16}, {229, 95, 28, 143}, {229, 95, 28, 239}}, {{229, 95, 28, 
         0}, {229, 95, 28, 64}, {229, 95, 28, 223}, {229, 95, 28, 
         191}, {229, 95, 28, 112}, {229, 95, 28, 223}, {229, 95, 28, 
         191}, {229, 95, 28, 32}}, {{229, 95, 28, 32}, {229, 95, 28, 
         16}, {229, 95, 28, 16}, {229, 95, 28, 175}, {229, 95, 28, 
         255}, {229, 95, 28, 127}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 
         48}}, {{229, 95, 28, 48}, {229, 95, 28, 239}, {229, 95, 28, 
         112}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 16}, {229, 95, 28, 
         16}, {229, 95, 28, 143}, {229, 95, 28, 239}}, {{229, 95, 28, 
         0}, {229, 95, 28, 64}, {229, 95, 28, 223}, {229, 95, 28, 
         191}, {229, 95, 28, 112}, {229, 95, 28, 223}, {229, 95, 28, 
         191}, {229, 95, 28, 32}}, {{229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 
         0}, {229, 95, 28, 16}, {229, 95, 28, 175}, {229, 95, 28, 
         255}, {229, 95, 28, 127}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 
         0}}, {{229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 
         0}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 16}, {229, 95, 28, 
         0}, {229, 95, 28, 0}, {229, 95, 28, 0}}}], {{0, 8}, {8, 
       0}}, {0, 255}, ColorFunction -> RGBColor], 
    BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
     Interleaving -> True, Magnification -> Automatic], 
    Selectable -> False], DefaultBaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics", 
   ImageSizeRaw -> {8, 8}, PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
   ImageSize -> {8, 9}];
```